# Отменить запрет выделения текста на странице

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

Всем доброго времени суток!

Студент, пишу курсовую работу, нашёл сайт с полезной информацией, но на нём не работает выделение текста на странице, не открывается контекстное меню, и вообще можно только смотреть и не трогать руками.

Само собой, руками я потрогал и через инструмент разработчика нашёл запреты на выделение текста, отображение контекстного меню и перетаскивания.

Немного потыкав консоль, пытаясь задать document.onselectstarted различные значения, решил не тратить время и просто скопипастить текст из кода страницы. (Первые страницы гугла по нескольким запросам ответа не дали)

Но всё равно остаётся интерес, как можно было бы отключить запрет на выделение текста на странице?

Ссылка на сайт http://www.engeco.ru/recognoscirovka.php
Блок скрипта с запретом - второй ребёнок body

Заранее спасибо!
(Надеюсь, кому-нибудь скрашу вечер такой задачкой)

Comment: Как вариант, поставить breakpoint до вызова функции и скопировать  что нужно

Comment: Отключить JS в браузере и в консоли отключить свойство CSS  `user-select`  (с вендорными префиксами в том числе) у `body`